# Function restriction by fixing an argument

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

How should I make function with lesser dimensionality than the original one by fixing an
argument of it:

For example I want to make successor function out of sum function as follows:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Now I am looking for something like this:

`g = f(~, 1)` which would be the successor function, i.e. `g(x) = x+1`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can write your own function:

```
def g(y):
    return f(2, y)
```

Or more concisely:

```
g = lambda y: f(2, y)
```

There's also `functools.partial`:

```
import functools

def f(x, y):
    return x + y

g = functools.partial(f, 2)
```

You can then call it as before:

```
>>> g(3)
5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do more than a little of this then you could use something like a decorator.

```
def with_x(x, fn, name=None):
  def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    return fn(x, *args, **kwargs)
  if name:
    foo.__name__ = name
return foo

def example(x,y):
  return x**y

g = with_x(2, example)

g(3)  #8
```

Use `name = parameter` if you care about the `__name__` of the resulting function. You could get fancier with other hacks into the enclosed function innards possibly using the `__inspect__` module if need be. But then you have re-written the previously mentioned `functools` partial stuff just to avoid having to give keyword arguments.