# can I replace some variables in a model using lmfit?

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm using a Python package called `lmfit` to create a model:

```
from lmfit import Model
def PnE(E, sigma, n, E_k, overlap):
    return ((1+np.exp(-(E_k-E)*sigma))**n*overlap)
```

To create a model, by instruction, I will do `model = Model(PnE)`.

However, I wonder if I can create a function, which allows me to replace the variables `sigma` and `n` with different values. In other words, I want to generate different models, which have similar structures but only differ by `sigma` and `n`. I tried

```
def fit_PnE(sigma, n):
    G = functools.partial(PnE, sigma, n)
    model = Model(G)
```

But it returns `NameError: name 'E_k' is not defined`. How can I define such a function that generates similar models? Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a function as a variable with one input fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028640/pass-a-function-as-a-variable-with-one-input-fixed)

Comment: how is "have similar structures but only differ by `sigma` and `n`" different from "are different model functions"?   You could create a more general version that your different (more restricted?) model functions call.  But also: you know that you could just fix the values of the `sigma`, `n`, `E_k`, or `overlap`  parameters when using the model, right?    As it turns out, `lmfit.Model` doesn't work with "partial functions" because it works by inspection of the call signature of the model function.

Comment: I know you're using `Model`, but what about creating different `Parameters`, and set `sigma` and `n` to `vary=False` and a specific value?