# How to pass function as variable with fixed argument

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python, but the second time I encouter this problem.
Problem:
In some libraries there are functions with arguments. Sometimes there is argument as function, like this:

```
def somefun(fun):
    x = [1,2,3]
    z = fun(x)
    return z
```

And I want to pass there some other function like this:

```
def func(x,y):
    return x*y
```

which have more than one argument. I want to make one argument static, so `somefun` except `func` as argument.

Finally I want to make some kind of cycle where I can change static arg.
Something like this:

```
for i in xrange(1,9):
    somefun(func(i,*))
```

Please do not offer me to change any functions. They are from library and it's not very comfortable to change them.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `def func2(y): return func(10, y)`?

Comment: You can use decorator to pas function.

Comment: Can you please be more specific which library you are using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function restriction by fixing an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159065/function-restriction-by-fixing-an-argument)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda statement:

```
somefun(lambda x: func(i, x))
```

Answer (score 1):

It sure sounds like you are looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). From the docs:

> `functools.partial(func, *args, **keywords)`
>
> > Return a new `partial` object which when called will behave like `func` called with the positional arguments `args` and keyword arguments `keywords`.

In your example, you could pass `partial(func, 10)` as the argument to `somefun`. Or you could create the `partial` objects and use them in a loop:

```
for i in xrange(1,9):
    somefun(partial(func, i))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with decorator

```
from functools import wraps
import numpy as np

def p_decorate(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args):
        z = f(*args)
        return z
    return wrapped

@p_decorate
def myfunc(a,b):
    """My new function"""
    z = np.dot(a,b)
    return z    

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,2,0]
r = myfunc(x,y)
print (r)   

print (myfunc.__name__)
print (myfunc.__doc__)
```

You can change myfunc as you wish.You can also insert more function layers.Without the use of this decorator factory,you would lose the name of myfunc and the docstring.